# Sights in London applicable to British Empire in Southeast Asia

Tags: sightseeing, london, history

Are there any historical sights in London concerning the British Empire's interests in Southeast Asia?

Examples:

- Statue of Sir Stamford Raffles
- Locations in London significant to the British Empire in Southeast Asia such as buildings or houses
- Statues or other memorials commemorating significant events for the British Empire in Southeast Asia.

Comment: You'd be interested in museums with exhibits on say British Burma and Malaya too right?

Comment: Correct. My focus is the Malay peninsula and Borneo but I wouldn't want to exclude British Burma.

Comment: Not a statue and the building, etc. isn't directly related, but the [British Museum contains several exhibits on southeast asia](https://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/galleries/asia/room_33_asia.aspx)

Comment: I wonder if there are enough people here with such concrete history knowledge to give you an answer. Maybe you want to ask for more concrete items if you can name those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fairly haphazard list, based off your description.

There's an exhibition of [Malay silverwork at the V&A Museum until July 2014](http://www.nst.com.my/nation/general/malay-silverwork-show-in-london-1.318971), and the [National Service exhibition at the National Army Museum contains exhibits from Malaya](http://www.nam.ac.uk/exhibitions/special-displays/national-service).

There's a statue of Sir Stamford in [Westminster Abbey](http://www.westminster-abbey.org/our-history/people/stamford-raffles), and one of Viscount William Slim (commander of British troops in Burma in WWII) at [Whitehall](http://www.ukattraction.com/london/statue-of-viscount-slim.htm).  The British "founders" of Penang (Francis Light), and Labuah (James Brooke)  don't merit the same attention, though [Brooke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Brooke) is buried in England, at Dartsmoor.

Some buildings established by the East India Company, originally repsonsible for the SE Asian interests, still exist, for example [the East India Club](http://www.eastindiaclub.co.uk/).  Unfortunately the old [East India House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_House) made way for [Lloyd's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_building).

A bit out of town, [Haileybury and Imperial Service College](http://www.haileybury.com/) used to be [the East India College](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_College) for training administrators.

The old [Colonial House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_and_Commonwealth_Office#History_of_the_Foreign_and_Commonwealth_Office_main_building), reported into by the Straits Settlements, still exists as the offices of the Foreign and Commonwealth now.

Comment: While over in London I stumbled across a [great exhibition on East India](http://www.rmg.co.uk/whats-on/exhibitions/traders) and immediately thought of this question. :)